# populating a multi - level hash

Tags: regex, perl, hash

I have this data set - I am only concerned with the class id, the process@server:
I am trying to load all three into a multi-level hash.

```
class_id: 995   (OCAive   )  ack_type: NOACK     supercede:  NO  copy:  NO  bdcst:  NO
PID                                    SENDS   RECEIVES   RETRANSMITS   TIMEOUTS MEAN    S.D.    #
21881  (rocksrvr@ith111          )          1          1             0          0
24519  (miclogUS@ith110          )          1          1             0          0
26163  (gkoopsrvr@itb101          )          1          1             0          0
28069  (sitetic@ith100           )         23          4             0          0
28144  (srtic@ithb10           )         33          5             0          0
29931  (loick@ithbsv115      )          1          1             0          0
87331  (rrrrv_us@ith102          )          1          1             0          0
                                  ---------- ----------    ---------- ---------- ------- ------- ------ 
                                          61         14             0          0
```

When i try and populate the hash, it does not get much (data dumper results below)

```
$VAR1 = '';
$VAR2 = {
    '' => undef
};
```

This is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
my $newcomm_dir = "/home/casper-compaq/work_perl/newcomm";
my $newcomm_file = "newcomm_stat_result.txt";

open NEWCOMM , "$new_comm_dir$newcomm_file";
while (<NEWCOMM>) {
    if ($_ =~ /\s+class_id:\s\d+\s+((\w+)\s+)/){
        my $message_class = $1;
    }
    if ($_ =~ /((\w+)\@\w+\s+)/) {
        my $process = $1;
    }
    if ($_ =~ /(\w+\@(\w+)\s+)/) {
        my $servers = $1;
    }

    my $newcomm_stat_hash{$message_class}{$servers}=$process;


    use Data::Dumper;
    print Dumper (%newcomm_stat_hash);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your main error is that your file is not opened, due to the path missing a `/`, between directory and filename. You can use the autodie pragma to check that the open succeeds, or you can use `or die "Can't open file: $!"`.

You have some scope issues. First off, `$message_class` will be undefined throughout the loop, since it's scope lasts only inside one iteration. You probably also want to have the hash outside the loop, if you want to be able to use it later on.

I put a `next` statement in the header line check, as the other checks will be invalid in that particular line. If you want to be more precise, you can put the whole thing outside the loop, and just do a single line check.

You do not need the two variables for process and server, just use them directly, and both at the same time.

Lastly, you probably want to send the reference to the hash to `Data::Dumper` in the print, else the hash will expand, and the print will be somewhat misleading.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use autodie;
my $newcomm_dir = "/home/casper-compaq/work_perl/newcomm/"; 
my $newcomm_file = "newcomm_stat_result.txt";

open my $fh, '<', "$new_comm_dir$newcomm_file";

my $message_class;
my %newcomm_stat_hash;
while (<$fh>) {
    if (/^\s+class_id:\s+\d+\s+\((\w+)\)\s+/){
        $message_class = $1;
        next;
    }
    if (/(\w+)\@(\w+)/) {
        $newcomm_stat_hash{$message_class}{$2}=$1;
    }
}
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \%newcomm_stat_hash;
```

Comment: the file was not being opened - and the varaibles were out of scope - scoping them at the root of the script (the beginning) populated the hash.    The consolidation of the deeper nodes of the hash, i really really like.   never seen it before, and it makes the hash much more readable. $newcomm_stat_hash{$message_class}{$2}=$1

Comment: @capser You should mark an answer with the green checkmark, to give credit to the best answer.

Comment: all of the comments were helpful but reducing some of the statement makes the code so much more readable. $newcomm_stat_hash{$message_class}{$2}=$1;

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the declarations problem, there are also multiple problems with your regex expressions. I would suggest making sure you get the expected output into each of the variables prior to trying to insert it into a hash.

For one thing you need to match parenthesis as `\(`, `\)` otherwise they are just interpreted as variable containers.

Comment: addind a slash to the end of the directory and making declarations at the top worked - thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your my declarations inside the if only have scope until the end of the if block, and your hash assignment shouldn't have a my.  Try declaring `%newcomm_stat_hash` before the while loop and `$message_class`, `$process`, and `$servers` at the top of the while block.

You also probably want to check your open for failure; I suspect you are missing a / there.

Answer (score 1):

Is your file being opened?

I think you need to change:

```
open NEWCOMM , "$new_comm_dir$newcomm_file";
```

To:

```
open NEWCOMM , $new_comm_dir.'/'.$newcomm_file;
```

Comment: yes - i should have and will from now on put the "or die $!;" after reading in a file. it is so embarrassing.